# JavaScript document.querySelector() not showing tag/element when logged to console in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a pretty simple web stack, just an `index.html` and a `dom.js` script. When I console log the variable that targets the element I want, I get odd behavior in Chrome Dev Console. I'm using "Chrome Version 104.0.5112.79 (Official Build) (x86_64)".

`const h1Tag = document.querySelector('h1');`

`console.log(h1Tag);`

**HTML File**

```
<head>
    <title>Javascript Demo</title>

    <style>

        h1 {
            color: red;
        }

        div {
            color: coral;
        }

    </style>
    
</head>

<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to JavaScript DOM Review</h1>
        <div class="output">Div 1</div>
        <div class="output">Div 2</div>

        <script src="dom.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**dom.js File**

```
const h1Tag = document.querySelector('h1');
console.log(h1Tag);

const divTags = document.querySelectorAll('div');
console.log(divTags);
```

What I expected to see in the console was the `<h1>Welcome to JavaScript DOM Review</h1>` but what I see most of the time is the `h1` element with a dropdown arrow that displays the `h1`'s properties.

If I refresh a few times, I get what I expect and that is the HTML element as an element.

Firefox nor Safari have the issue.

It's more of a nuisance than a show stopper.

Thanks!

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXYY9.png)
[image]

Comment: The later screenshot shows a `NodeList` which is something that is not returned by `document.querySelector` but by `document.querySelectorAll`. Mind telling us the exact code you're actually runnning in these browsers?

Comment: You'd like to see the outerHTML of the h1Tag?  `console.log(h1Tag.outerHTML)`

Comment: @Domino Here is he code sample...that would help lol.

Comment: @James By default, when selecting the only element will produce the html, but I don't always get the result I expected.

Comment: use `console.dir(h1Tag)` to view list of properties

Comment: @Mike I don't want to view the properties, I want to view the HTML tag only.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot seem to replicate this but perhaps it is to do with the way that chrome loads the dom?

Does putting it inside the following help:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    const h1Tag = document.querySelector('h1');
    console.log(h1Tag);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and while this does work, I shouldn't have to do this for one element, by default, document.querySelector should just output the element. But I could see your response being helpful.